# .FormatString property having no effect on binding

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this line in my code

```
UserLoginLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Foo, "bar.Username"));
```

Which display the username (and just the username) in the textbox correctly. How come this code

```
Binding b = new Binding("Text", Foo, "bar.Username")
{
    FormatString = "Logged in as {0}.",
    FormattingEnabled = true
};
UserLoginLabel.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

has the exact same effect? Is this not how to format a data binding?

Comment: I think `FormatString` is intended to be just the format characters - e.g. `"C2"` for formatting currency. Not sure how to go about formatting a string like that. Maybe you need to supply a custom `FormatInfo`.

Comment: You can simply not format a string. Formatting (i.e. converting a type to a string) works for numeric types, date and time, TimeSpan and enums. In the immediate window I can write `$@"{3.14:Logged in as 0.00\.}"` which prints `Logged in as 3.14`, but replacing the number by a string just prints the string, no matter how the format looks like.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, it works when `FormatString` is just the format characters. For example to display a percent: `new Binding("Text", Foo, "bar.Opacity", true) { FormatString = "P0" }`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `Format` event for this:

```
var b = new Binding("Text", Foo, "bar.Username");
b.FormattingEnabled = true;
b.Format += b_Format;
UserLoginLabel.DataBindings.Add(b);

private void b_Format(Object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType == typeof(String))  //optional, you decide
        e.Value = $"Logged in as {e.Value}.";
}
```

What you have to watch out for is that this will be called *every time* the value is to be formatted.  That can happen for multiple reasons, so you could get an already-formatted `e.Value`.